# Is it possible to modify Javascript by diazo?

Tags: diazo

How can I substitude "image.png" in the javascript of the theme by content's //div/img/@src using diazo?

Content:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/plone/example/@@download/image/any.png" width="640" height="360" />
</div>
```

Theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.anystretch("image.png", {speed: 150});
</script>
```

Comment: ok, this can rather simple be achieved by bringing the content div into the theme and some not challenging javascript.